# Getting a (text)selection on a specific page in PDFNet

Tags: pdfnet

In java, something like PDFView.getSelection(currPage) is possible, 
but in PDFNet it's not possible to call the GetSelection() method with a parameter, it returns the text on the first page only.

How can i get a selection on a specific page in PDFNet?

Comment: which platform is this for? Android?

Comment: i'm using winforms in visual studio

Answer (score 0):

There is PDFViewCtrl.[GetSelection](http://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/docs/PDFNet/?topic=html/M_pdftron_PDF_PDFViewCtrl_GetSelection_1.htm)(page_num) that will return any selection on the specified page.

If there is no actual selection on that page, then PDFViewCtrl.Selection.[GetQuads](http://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/docs/PDFNet/?topic=html/M_pdftron_PDF_PDFViewCtrl_Selection_GetQuads.htm) will return an empty array.

Comment: Nope it doesn't have that when i using winforms, i might have an older version, going to check it asap

Comment: That function has been available since 2010, for our PDFViewCtrl class for PDFNet .Net. Can you let me know the PDFNet Dll filename, and the version number from the Windows Explorer file properties (or call PDFNet.GetVersion at runtime) that you are using.

Comment: filename: PDFNet.dll, version at runtime: 5,1

Comment: I see. 5.1 was released September 2010, so apparently you need to update to the latest version. Please contact support at pdftron using your company email address. https://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/whatsnew.html

Comment: Thank you for your help ;) .

Comment: would you maybe know an answer to this one too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240575/saving-the-color-of-an-annotation-in-pdftron-pdfnet-winforms